# How to handle API code 400 errors by error message in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, error-handling

I am working on a project with react, and I am new to it.
I would like to raise the following question.
I have a POST API that throws errors on some occasions. I can handle the errors by error code (e.g. 400, 401, 402, 500). But I would like to have more cases of error code 400
e.g.

```
OnSend = () => {
    MyService.SendPost(this.state.enteredValue) //do the POST request
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({result: 'success'});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            switch(error.errorCode) {
                case 400:
                    this.setState({result: '400')};
                        break;
                case 500:
                    this.setState({result: '500')};
                    break;
            }
        });
};
```

What I would like to do is something like the following

```
OnSend = () => {
    MyService.SendPost(this.state.enteredValue)
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({result: 'success'});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            switch(error.errorCode) {
                case 400:
                    switch(error.ERRORMESSAGEHERE) { //how should I handle this?
                        case 'error message 1':
                            this.setState({result: '400 with error message 1')};
                            break;
                        case 'error message 2':
                            this.setState({result: '400 with error message 2')};
                            break;
                      }
                      break;
                case 500:
                    this.setState({result: '500')};
                    break;
            }
        });
};
```

I hope that the above example may help.
Is something like that feasible?

Comment: Why don't you only check if error.errorCode  is 500, otherwise setState to the error message you received?

Comment: I agree with Erik, also try to standardize your approach and perhaps create some helper functions or components so you don't have 50 lines of boilerplate every network request.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make this clear. The above code is an example. It is not about 500 or 400. It is about having different `results` for the 400 error code messages.

Comment: For better understanding. The POST is happening in the backend and I want to react to change things in the frontend. Since I am new to react I would appreciate a solution to the above. Thanks for your comments and for looking into this

Comment: So far I have find only the ComponentDidCatch(). However, I think that this is will not solve my problem